# Yii framework - what is the file ".yii" in some folders

Tags: php, frameworks, yii

There is ".yii" file in the following folders:

- /assets/
- /images/
- /protected/commands/shell/
- /protected/extensions/
- /protected/messages/
- /protected/runtime/
- /protected/views/system/
- /themes/classic/views/layouts/
- /themes/classic/views/site/
- /themes/classic/views/system/

What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe they are generated by yiic, not sure what purpose they have though as they always appear to be empty unless they are purely used as a means of storing a timestamp against the build date.

Answer (score 2):

i assumed it was some kind of placeholder to stop mercurial/git from ignoring the directory

Comment: Interesting enough, for me, git still ignored the directory (I just realized after cloning to another machine that directories with only .yii file in them are not in repository) - so I added .gitignore files instead. I hope it's safe to delete .yii files.